# How to change Magento currency ISO code

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have installed a **Magento store** and set up the currency as **Pakistani Rupee**.

It automatically shows **PKR**  with the price which I don't want, I want to show as **RS**.

So from where I can change that **ISO code** for the currency?

Answer (score 0):

To change currency of your Magento site

- In admin panel, go to `Admin > System > Configuration > Currency` Set
  up.
- Select currency that you want to be default from your base currency
  drop down.
- Select the same currency in the Default Display Currency drop down
  and from the Allowed Currencies list.
- Click `Save Config`.

and after that you should go to `“System->Manage Currency Rates”` and set rates for currencies you’ve chosen if no rates are defined there.

The frontend display currency should be different if you check out your site.

Make sure you've cleared your cache before checking.

Comment: This is how you add a currency. As i mentioned that currency is setted up already its Pakistani rupee. And the price is now showing as PKR 120  but i want it to show as RS 120

Comment: I understood your query. Please go to `Admin > System > Configuration > General > Currency Setup` and set "Indian Rupee" as values of `Base Currency`, `Default Display Currency`, `Allowed Currencies`. Your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

In magento 2 you can change currency symbol in admin > stores > currency symbols